# What level of UV protection is recommended for glacier travel?

Tags: hiking, glaciers, sunglasses, uv-protection

What level of UV protection is recommended for glacier travel? For example, I have sunglasses which says 40% UV layer. Will this be ok for glacier trekking, or do I need glasses with higher level of protection?

Comment: Related [At what point do I need snow goggles or glacier glasses when hiking?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/at-what-point-do-i-need-snow-goggles-or-glacier-glasses-when-hiking) & [How much side protection should sunglasses have?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8365/how-much-side-protection-should-sunglasses-have)

Answer (score 11):

Snow blindness is at best very painful. UV damage to your eyes is not something you want to play around with. If only 40% protection they are are not sunglasses, they are fashion accessories and offer no where near enough to protect your eyes for more than an hour.

For $10 you will get glasses that provide 99% protection, why risk it?